# Merge multi-dimensional arrays with common id

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two multi-dimensional arrays:

First array Pizzas:

```
0 => array:2 [▼
    "pizza_id" => 11
    "pizza_name" => "Hawaï"
]
1 => array:2 [▼
    "pizza_id" => 12
    "pizza_name" => "Tonno"
]
2 => array:2 [▼
    "pizza_id" => 13
    "pizza_name" => "Surprise"
]
```

Second array Ingredients:

```
0 => array:4 [▼
    "pizza_id" => 11
    "ingredient_one" => "Ananas"
    "ingredient_two" => "Onion"
    "ingredient_three" => "Ham"
]
1 => array:4 [▼
    "pizza_id" => 12
    "ingredient_one" => "Tuna"
    "ingredient_two" => "Onion"
    "ingredient_three" => null
]
```

I want to merge these two arrays linking them by `pizza_id`. One of the Pizza Ids has no matching array for ingredients (the ingredients are unknown) so for this Pizza I want to set ingredients to `null` and get the next array:

New array PizzaAndIngredients:

```
0 => array:5 [▼
    "pizza_cid" => 11
    "pizza_name" => "Hawaï"
    "ingredient_one" => "Ananas"
    "ingredient_two" => "Onion"
    "ingredient_three" => "Ham"
]
1 => array:5 [▼
    "pizza_id" => 12
    "pizza_name" => "Tonno"
    "ingredient_one" => "Tuna"
    "ingredient_two" => "Onion"
    "ingredient_three" => null
]
2 => array:5 [▼
    "pizza_id" => 13
    "pizza_name" => "Surprise"
    "ingredient_one" => null
    "ingredient_two" => null
    "ingredient_three" => null
]
```

I have been fiddling around with `array_merge`, `foreach`, etc but can not get the array. The alternative is to build a new query and left-join pizzas and ingredients but in real life the arrays are much more complicated and this would mean duplicating a lot of code.

I was hoping for a more efficient solution of merging the two multi-dimensional array's.

My last attempt is:

```
$PizzaAndIngredients = array();
foreach ($pizzas as $key => $values) {
    $PizzaAndIngredients[$key] = array_merge($ingredients, $values);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch the rows from the query results you can set the array keys equal to the `pizza_id`, or re-index them by the `pizza_id`:

```
$pizza       = array_column($pizza, null, 'pizza_id');
$ingredients = array_column($ingredients, null, 'pizza_id');
```

Then just create a default array of `null`s to use if the `$ingredients` don't exist and then merge `$ingredients` values with the `$pizza` values:

```
//get an ingredient array
$temp    = reset($ingredients);
//combine keys and an array of nulls
$default = array_combine(array_keys($temp),
                         array_fill(0, count($temp), null));

foreach($pizza as $id => $p_values) {
    //check if $ingredients[$id] exists, if not use the default
    $i_values    = isset($ingredients[$id]) ? $ingredients[$id] : $default;
    //you can also use just $result[] if you don't need the pizza_id as key
    $result[$id] = array_merge($i_values, $p_values); 
}
```

Comment: Looks like a interesting way to go. Is there a more efficient way to create the default (null) array? Since the ingredients array in reality has over 30 values. Could I copy an existing ingredients-array and set all values to null?

Comment: Yes.  Edited a dynamic default.

Comment: Tested and worked! Awesome! Thanks a lot. Btw. I found a slightly more efficiënt way to set the default null arrya: $keys = array_keys(reset($ingredients));
$default = array_fill_keys($keys, null);